# Intersection Observer - highlight current section

Tags: navbar, viewport, highlight, sections, intersection-observer

I'm trying to activate and deactivate a class for navbar items whenever a section is either **partially** in view or **partially** out of view. The code works fine if I scroll down or up the page completely. The problem is if I change direction in the middle of a section.

It seems that the section needs to be out of view 100% first and then come back into view in order for the class to activate or deactivate (I believe this happens because we're checking if `entry.isIntersecting` is true and it first needs to be changed to false). Nonetheless, this results in an unwanted behavior.

I've tried fiddling with the if statement to check with the `entry.intersectionRatio`, but I can't seem to make it work either. I've also tried in different browsers, just in case, but the behavior is still the same.

How do I come around this?

Here is some [code](https://codepen.io/mishunov/pen/opeRdL) that shows this "buggy" behavior. It looks like this:

```
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('div.screen');
const config = {
  rootMargin: '-50px 0px -55%'
};

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(function (entries, self) {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      intersectionHandler(entry); 
    }
  });
}, config);

sections.forEach(section => {
  observer.observe(section);
});

function intersectionHandler(entry) {
  const id = entry.target.id;
  const currentlyActive = document.querySelector('nav li.active');
  const shouldBeActive = document.querySelector('nav li[data-ref=' + id + ']');

  if (currentlyActive) {
    currentlyActive.classList.remove('active');
  }
  if (shouldBeActive) {
    shouldBeActive.classList.add('active');
  }
}
```

The codepen is from [this](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/01/deferring-lazy-loading-intersection-observer-api/) article.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I've been playing with your CodePen and found a way to fix the issue.

The main idea is to make sure that only one element can be in the `root` at the same time. To achieve that you need to do two things:

First, the `rootMargin` height should be as thin as possible.

```
rootMargin: '-45% 0px -55%'
```

The second thing is to add a margin to your `.screen` CSS class.

```
  margin-top: 3px;
```

(1 or 2 px may be too small)

The code worked fine with Firefox and Chrome but didn't work on Safari that doesn't seem to implement the InstersectionObserver API. I don't have Windows so I can't test Edge and IE.

Answer (score 2):

You have to explicitly define your root in your observer options because your demo runs inside an iframe and rootMargin is otherwise ignored. Then make the observers height as small as possible using `rootMargin`.

```
const config = { 
   root: document,
   rootMargin: '-50% 0 -50%'
}
```